# Timer is Off, code possibly taking too long to compile before it ticks?

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm using a `Threading.DispatcherTimer` and every tick of the timer runs a subroutine.

Is it possible that if the subroutine takes longer then 1s for the processor to finish that it will mess up the time of the timer that is counting in seconds?

```
Try
  timercount = Nothing
  timercount = New DispatcherTimer()
  timercount.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
  timercount.Start()
  AddHandler timercount.Tick, AddressOf TickMe 'Every Second the 'TickMe' Method runs
Catch ex As Exception
  '  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

---

```
Private Sub TickMe()
  CL(0).Actual = H.Actual

  TextBoxSerialNumber.Focus()

  IntSec = IntSec + 1

  H.ActualBoxTime = H.ActualBoxTime.AddSeconds(1) 
  CL(0).ActualBoxTime = H.ActualBoxTime

  If IntSec Mod 60 = 0 Then
    H.Actual = H.Actual + 1
    CL(0).Actual = H.Actual
  End If

  CL(0).TargetBox = H.TargetBox

  PopulateCutGrid(CL)
End Sub
```

I've found after 50-60 minutes of counting it's off by almost 10 minutes!

Comment: That's never going to work. Code could be too busy to execute teh handler is only one problem. Read the system clock every "second" would be better.

Comment: I Can't do that, even if I use System Clock to update, i need the total seconds for various other reasons in my program.

Comment: Huh? first time it executes to store the time, after that number of seconds is now - first_time. 1 second timer firing 60 times is not going to be a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) regarding DispatchTimer:

> Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs. This is because DispatcherTimer operations are placed on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in the queue and their priorities.

If you need something more precise, I would recommend [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). Each time the method of this timer is invoked, a ThreadPool thread is used. From this article:

> The callback method executed by the timer should be reentrant, because it is called on ThreadPool threads. The callback can be executed simultaneously on two thread pool threads if the timer interval is less than the time required to execute the callback, or if all thread pool threads are in use and the callback is queued multiple times.

Also forgot to mention that you'll need to use `Invoke` and `InvokeRequired` for WinForms or `Dispatcher` for WPF (I think, since I don't use WPF).

---

**Edit 1:**

Regarding your comment about needing total seconds, you can just store the original `DateTime` somewhere, and total seconds would be calculated using `(DateTime.Now - StoredDateTime).TotalSeconds()`. I would also recommend reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) about threading in WPF to see if it applies in your case.

---

**Edit2:**

Actually, since I think the only thing you're after is a precise count of elapsed time, you could use a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to keep track of time. Try using the regular `DispatchTimer` and just refer to the stopwatch each "tick" of that timer. That way, the Stopwatch is what keeps track of time, not the timer that could be used just for updating the UI.

Comment: Gimme a couple minutes to implement, and i'll upvote/accept if it makes a difference.

Comment: Actually it will be a bit longer, since i have to wait X amount of time before i will be able to notice the time being off

Comment: hmm,.... after 10 minutes of running, it's 8 seconds off. this is going to run for probably 8+ hours at a time, at the end of 8 hours it will be 6 minutes and 24 seconds off, and although that's a hell of a lot more accurate then the dispatcher timer, that's not gonna fly <.<

Comment: I'm assuming this is the best answer i will recieve, i can set 
H.ActualBoxTime = DateTime.Now, but it's kind of imperative that intSec is dead on, anyway, Thanks

Comment: Just edited in a more precise idea if you want to take another look.

Comment: I've heard bad things about using system.diagnostics in production code :P

Comment: I dunno I could of swore I read somewhere not to, anyway after reading some of the documentation maybe i'll give stopwatch a go,... when i think of diagnostics i don't think of a real time class, i think of Error checking, statistics, and other slow stuff

Comment: The `System.Diagnostics` namespace contains classes that provide interaction with processes, performance counters, event logs, and tools related to debugging code. `Stopwatch` is mainly used to provide precise time, usually when profiling some code. The best solution is still to use `DateTime`, but, if you don't want that, `Stopwatch` is your next best choice. Also, the only performance consideration you generally need to consider relates to inefficient looping, not really O(1) operations.